# Wireless transmission of sound

Tags: speakers, wireless

My original question was about a specific product but was marked off-topic. I've been doing more research since then in to the capabilities of wireless sound transmission and am surprised at the lack of available tech.

Is it at all possible, outside of dlna or similar standards, to reliably transcode speaker output to digital for wireless transmission and receive that signal wirelessly to convert back to speaker output (which would obviously need to be powered)?

The offerings that I've found barely seem to scrape the surface of what I would have thought feasible. We have been doing exactly this with simple FM radio for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any decent wireless transmitter will allow you to transmit line level audio. You nevertheless will need either powered loudspeakers at the receiving side, or a power amplifier plus passive loudspeakers.

Some wireless transmitters accept digital audio inputs (AES-EBU mostly), most receivers will have an option to output analog audio.

Be aware that transmitting multi-channels audio thru several mono wireless transmitter might lead to phase issues at the reproduction stage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with DLNA, but I've used wireless IEMs several times to send the signal from a console to a couple of active speakers. I'm guessing that the same method would work with standalone amps as well, possibly also to link amps together.

How reliable this actually is I don't know. It has worked for smaller gigs where I'm only using wireless mics and the layout of the room makes it difficult to pull cables from FOH to the speakers.